# Tweaking ES2015 Map to support desired behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am playing around with ES2015 Maps and I am discovering that it is a great feature. However, I now have a use case that I cannot quite figure out whether or not can work out with Maps.

Consider my class

```
class A {
     constructor(public a:number) {}
     public equals(obj: A): boolean {
         return this.a === obj.a;
     }
 }
```

As far as I understand will ES2015 Maps use the === equality operator (with some exceptions). Thus I wonder if it is possible to kind of overwrite the equality and force it to use the `A` object's `equals(...)` method if instanceof?

Ultimately this is what I would like to achieve:

```
var map = new Map();
map.set(new A(8), 7)
map.get(new A(8))      // return 7, not undefined
```

Do you think I have to create my own Map class to implement this behavior that checks if both objects are instances of `A` and then call the `equals(...)` method?

Comment: No, such is not (yet?) possible. But you could use `map.set(instance.a, 7)`

Comment: Related https://esdiscuss.org/topic/maps-with-object-keys

Comment: Related #2 https://esdiscuss.org/topic/maps-with-object-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create subclass and override `get` method as you need:

```
class MapByEquals extends Map {
  get(key) {
    for(var k of this.keys()) {
      if(key.equals(k)) {
        return super.get(k);
      }
    }
    return super.get(key);
  }
}
```

```js
"use strict";
class A {
  constructor(a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  equals(b) {
    return this.a === b.a;
  }
}

class MapByEquals extends Map {
  get(key) {
    for(var k of this.keys()) {
      if(key.equals(k)) {
        return super.get(k);
      }
    }
    return super.get(key);
  }
}

var map = new MapByEquals();
map.set(new A(8), 7)
console.log(map.get(new A(8)))
```

Be aware that Babel doesn't support native classes extension. But most browsers (Chrome 42+, Firefox 45+) support classes natively and it will work.

Comment: Of course this also turns a structure with O(log n) access into an O(n) one. @Bergi's suggestion in the comment of the question, i.e. to use regular Map with keys as a unique-ish hash / id, is preferable if possible.